# Html.BeginForm not submitting when using .trigger('submit')

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, asp.net-core, razor

So I'm using razor views and JS/jQuery. I have a form that I simply cannot get to work the way I need it to. Based on my debugging, I'm just not hitting the controller at all. I think the form is just never actually submitting. I feel like the solution below should help, but I just dont understand why it isnt. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CheckSubmit() {
       // do some stuff

        $('#myForm').trigger('submit');      
        return true;
    }

    function htmlEncode(value) {
        return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
    }
</script>

<div id="stuff" style="display: none">
    <div id="otherStuff">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("MyControllerMethod", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserItem.UserId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserCert.CertificateSubject)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.comments)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IsReactivationRequest)

            <div>
                <a id="btnHideDetails">
                    <span>Close</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            // displays some information
 
            <div style="padding-bottom: 15px">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.radioBtnValue, "approve")Approve <br />

                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.radioBtnValue, "reject")Reject <br />
            </div>

            <div id="txtComments" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <div>Comments:</div>
                <div>
                    @(Html.TextArea("commentBox", new { maxlength = 2000, cols = 70, rows = 5 }))
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="btnSubmitDiv" style="display: none;">
            <input id="btnSubmit" onclick="return CheckSubmit();" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now all of the js is contained in the cshtml file. I know there are other ways of submitting this form, but for some reason this specific solution is not working and I need to understand why. Thank you!

Comment: Assuming, for whatever reason, that you cannot put the submit button within the form (which you ***really*** should be, for a lot of accessibility/fallback reasons) then call the `submit` event on the native form reference, not the jquery object: `$('#myForm')[0].submit()`

Comment: So I moved the div containing the submit input into the form, but still got the same result

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code,and it can work:

View:

```
<div id="stuff" >
    <div id="otherStuff">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("TestJquery", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
        {
            
            <input name="UserId" />

            <div>
                <a id="btnHideDetails">
                    <span>Close</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            // displays some information

            <div style="padding-bottom: 15px">
              
            </div>

            <div id="txtComments" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <div>Comments:</div>
                <div>
                    @(Html.TextArea("commentBox", new { maxlength = 2000, cols = 70, rows = 5 }))
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="btnSubmitDiv">
            <input id="btnSubmit" onclick="CheckSubmit()" type="button" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CheckSubmit() {
            // do some stuff

            $('#myForm').trigger('submit');
        }

       
    </script>
```

action：

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestJquery() {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TestJquery(string UserId)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

result:
[image]